# Playing sequential videos from array in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play a series of videos in an array in Android, however when the below code runs only the last element / video of the array plays.

How can I loop through the array and play the videos one after the other?

I get the feeling that the continuation of the loop happens immediately after the videoView.start() command so only the last one plays.

Here is an approximation of my code...

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String file_location = "path/to/my/files/"; // external storage
    String filepaths[] = {"1_A.mp4", "1_B.mp4"}; // array could have many more elements

    for(String filepath: filepaths){
        String path = file_location + filepath;
        videoView.setVideoPath(path);
        videoView.start();
    }
```

I have tried adding the setOnCompletionListener and putting the continue inside the onCompletion but the error is "continue outside of loop"

```
videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            continue;
        }
    });
```

How can I play each video sequentially with as little / no gap in between?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use loop because you are supposed to set the path of the next video only after previous one finished so instead of loop create a field called `currentPlayingIndex` make it increment after each video finishes and then set path from that ....

Like this

```
    private int currentPlayingIndex; // Keep this as gloabal variable

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    String file_location = "path/to/my/files/"; // external storage
    String filepaths[] = {"1_A.mp4", "1_B.mp4"}; // array could have many more elements


    String path = file_location + filepaths[currentPlayingIndex];
    videoView.setVideoPath(path);
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            currentPlayingIndex++; //Increment index here
            if(currentPlayingIndex < filepaths.length)
            {
                String newPath = file_location + filepaths[currentPlayingIndex];
                videoView.setVideoPath(newPath);
                videoView.start();
            }else {
                //Add logic here when all videos are played
            }
        }
    });
```

Note: I am not sure how long it will take to switch between videos ...

Comment: I was just about to post exactly that! You get my upvote! One suggestion though mainly for the OP: try to avoid hardcoding your paths. It will most probably cause issues in the future. Also in Java String[ ] filepaths is preferred to String filepaths[ ]

Answer (score 0):

The first: You need to play *.mp4 in the array of index 0.

Then when the video play complet,use the player play the *.mp4 in the array of index next.

My English expression may not be very good, I hope you can understand